# Compile error in C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have written a library called "myprotocol" in c++ using QT creator as IDE and the normal make command to compile, I have tested the library in a a seperate project as a testbed and the library works perfectly.

Later I try to use the library in another project which uses b2 tool to compile its sources. I am able to link against the myprotocol library but I get strange output errors saying that I have problem in the original "myprotocol" library project, which is not correct.

Here are the errors:

```
/home/HA/myprotocol/archive.hpp:371:25: error: declaration of ‘operator&’ as non-function
/home/HA/myprotocol/archive.hpp:371:23: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
/home/HA/myprotocol/archive.hpp:371:41: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
```

This is the the line which contains the error:

```
iarchive& operator&(CDBRequest& buf);
```

This is the definition of the CDBRequest:

```
class CDBRequest
{
public:

CDBRequest() : _cdb_request(0)
{}

CDBRequest(uint16 value)
{
    _cdb_request = uint32(value) << 16;
}

CDBRequest& operator=(uint32 cdb_request)
{
    _cdb_request = cdb_request;
    return *this;
}

void set_value(uint16 value)
{
    _cdb_request = uint32(value) << 16;
}

operator uint32&() { return _cdb_request; }

private:
    uint32 _cdb_request;

};
```

This is the command I use to compile my project in b2:

```
b2 variant=release link=static toolset=gcc include=/home/HA/myprotocol/ linkflags="-L /home/HA/myprotocol/ -lmyprotocol"
```

Can anyone tell me what might be the problem?

Comment: please post more code for the context in which `operator&` is declared.

Comment: If I want to post the rest of the code, it would be really long. What I did currently is I removed that line of code and tried to implement its function in a different way. But now I have new problem which is more strange, some of the header files cannot be seen by the project. I am defining the scope correctly, but I cannot see the declaration inside these files, like they don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the problem:

In the library project I have a header file called "types.hpp", later when I test it in the testbed project, I only have one cpp file.

But eventually when I test it in the root project, the root project has also a header file named "types.hpp" so when I changed the name of the file everything went smoothly.

I think the problem also is because of the #ifdef for both files since they have also the same name.

Comment: With those "#ifdef"s, I guess you mean the include guards, right? If so, take the habit of adding some pseudo-random data (e.g. the hash of a timestamp) or something else that makes it less likely that names collide. Remember, they don't have to be readable but only unique!

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I means the include guards ,I will take your tip.